# How to find the optimal SSOR parameter

Tags: iterative-method, preconditioning

The symmetric successive overrelaxation method features the iteration matrix

$$P=\left(\frac{D}{\omega}+L\right)\frac{\omega}{2-\omega}D^{-1}\left(\frac{D}{\omega}+U\right)$$

Either as a stationary method or as a preconditioner, a system in that matrix is solved at every iteration.

The method depends on a parameter $\omega \in (0,2)$. While it converges for every $\omega$ in that parameter range, there is little information in standard textbooks on how to find the optimal parameter in practice. Often, $\omega = 1$ is a choice without further discussion.

What are practical ways of picking a relaxation parameter? Or is picking the parameter a purely theoretical issue?

Comment: the book by Axelsson & Barker has a discussion. It comes down to the fact that for SSOR the optimal parameter is much less important than for SOR.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, $\omega=1.2$ is often used in practice when using SSOR as a preconditioner in an outer iteration. The way to find which value is optimal is simply one of trying many different values and recording how many iterations you need to solve a linear system to a certain accuracy. It's a one-dimensional optimization problem (the parameter is $\omega$, the objective function is the number of iterations), so easy enough to solve by simply sampling many different values of $\omega$.

Comment: So in practice it comes down to trial and error? That sounds bleak.

Comment: It's a 1d optimization problem, that really isn't all that hard. Or you could just accept the value of 1.2 that others have found as gospel.

Answer (score 1):

Corless/Fillion [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461484529) gives a formula for "optimal" $\omega$ of SOR but doesn't say where it comes from. Here's the relevant section:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps in some way, but in [the book Numerical Recipes](http://www.numerical.recipes/), the authors have this to say about the SOR parameter $\omega$ and how it can be iteratively updated:

[image]

where

[image]

Please note that the context where these conclusions were drawn in the book comes from considerations of a 2D SOR scheme, and they mention nothing about the impact of this update scheme on the SSOR. Also, the intermediate calculation step, denoted with bracketed indices $1/2$ and $n+1/2$ come from the 2D red-black SOR scheme, where first even-even and odd-odd `i,j` coordinates are solved, and then even-odd and odd-even `i,j` are solved. `i,j` here are indices of the grid points along the $x$ and $y$ axes, respectively

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. That seems to require a good approximation for the spectral radius of the Jacobi iteration matrix, and that this spectral radius is less than 2.

Comment: Speaking only from the perspective of SOR, the formula given for rho_Jacobi in the Numerical Recipes (and in my post, as a snapshot) seems to be a good approximation.